# Search a code line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I'm developing a code in Eclipse (java). While debugging the code, I used a lot of `System.out.println(...)`. Now I need to delete all these lines. To do this, I wrote `System.out.println` in Search->Java, but it hasn't provided any search result. So, how can I find all occurancies of this string `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search -> File. Input "System.out.println" and select the type of files you want to search in "*.java" (without quotes)

The "Java search" is something different. It doesn't allow you to find stuff in java files but methods/declarations/etc. in java files. For instance declare somewhere in your project "String canYou = "FindMe?";" and then do Search -> Java, input "String" and select "Type" and hit search. It should find all the String uses in you project, including the aforementioned one.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing `System.out.println` anywhere in your project, select this text and afterwards press `ctrl + alt + g` (sorry don't know exactly what kind of search this stands for) and it will give you all the occurrences of this string in all your projects(workspace-wise). I'm 100% sure it stands for exactly something in search > java - you can take a closer look to see for exactly what. Other than that you can have a conditional execution for the logs - i.e

```
if(Consts.DEBUG){
    Log("something");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

press Control + H

this will open up the search window, go to File Search tab and look for the system.out.println(

Answer (score 0):

just search for `println`.  I bet eclipse is interpreting what you are putting in as a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would do Find usages on the println method (ctrl+shift+g)

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu Search->File and in the "Containing Text" field type in "System.out.println*", in the "File name patterns" field type in "*.java". Now press  the "Replace" button in the lower right corner. Leave blank the "With" field and click the "Preview" button. Uncheck any occurrences you want to keep and then press "OK".

You may want to make sure your code is in version control before attempting this in case you do it wrong and want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

We have written an eclipse plugin to do the same. It will find the System.out.println in your java code and comment it out. We will soon have a version which will delete it also. Hope this is useful.

http://eclipseo.blogspot.in/2013/05/commenting-systemoutprintln-from.html